# Is sheaf stability an open condition?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. If $E$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$, we write its Hilbert polynomial:
$$P_E(m) = \alpha^E_dm^d + O(m^{d-1}).$$
We say $E$ is *Gieseker stable* if $E$ is pure and $P_F/\alpha^F_d < P_E/\alpha^E_d$ for all nontrivial $F \subset E$.

> Suppose we have a family of coherent sheaves on $X$. If this family contains a Gieseker stable member, does it follow that the general member is also Gieseker stable?

I am also interested in the same question in the situation where all the sheaves are locally free and *Gieseker stability* is replaced with *slope stability*.

Comment: Yes: see *The Geometry of Moduli Spaces of Sheaves* by Huybrechts and Lehn, Proposition 2.3.1.

Comment: Is this true for Bridgeland stability and complexes of sheaves as well?